# AWS Cognito Exception while uploading a file to s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
    identityClient.setEndpoint("cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    identityClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
    GetIdRequest idRequest = new GetIdRequest();
    idRequest.setAccountId("XXXXXXXXX");
    idRequest.setIdentityPoolId("XXXXXXX");
    GetIdResult idResp = identityClient.getId(idRequest);
    String identityId = idResp.getIdentityId();
    GetOpenIdTokenRequest tokenRequest = new GetOpenIdTokenRequest();
    tokenRequest.setIdentityId(identityId);
    GetOpenIdTokenResult tokenResp = identityClient.getOpenIdToken(tokenRequest);
    String openIdToken = tokenResp.getToken();
    AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
    AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest stsReq = new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest();
    stsReq.setRoleArn(
            "arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-1:XXXXXX:identitypool/us-east-1:XXXXXXX");
    stsReq.setWebIdentityToken(openIdToken);
    stsReq.setRoleSessionName("AppTestSession");


    AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult stsResp = stsClient.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(stsReq);
    Credentials stsCredentials = stsResp.getCredentials();

    AWSSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(stsCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
            stsCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(), stsCredentials.getSessionToken());
    Date sessionCredentialsExpiration = stsCredentials.getExpiration();
    System.out.println("session credentials expiration -> " + sessionCredentialsExpiration);

    String bucketName = "s3fileupload";
    String keyName = "cognitokey";
    String uploadFileName = "/home/fresher/Downloads/say-hello.jpg";
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(sessionCredentials);
    s3client.setEndpoint("s3fileupload.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com");

    File file = new File(uploadFileName);
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file));
}
```

I am getting an exception which says "Request ARN is invalid ".
Could you please guide me through this?

Request ARN is invalid (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

Answer (score 0):

In your STS request you are passing in the Cognito Identity's ARN, not the Role Arn that you want to get credentials for.

The value here should be be the ARN for the role you configured in IAM. It will look something like this:

arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ROLE_NAME